# Argument 'appCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am using latest Karma Angular.js unit testing.

I have an error: '**Argument 'appCtrl' is not a function, got undefined**'.

appCtrl.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('appCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.count = 5;

    $scope.incrementCount = function() {
        $scope.count = $scope.count + 1;
    };

});
```

appCtrl.spec.js:

```
describe('Controller test', function(){

    var appCtrl, $scope;

    beforeEach(module('app'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        appCtrl = $controller('appCtrl', {
            $scope: $scope
        });
    }));

    it('should have appCtrl controller toBeDefined', function() {
        expect(appCtrl).toBeDefined();
    });

    iit('should init counter value', function() {
        expect($scope.count).toBeDefined();
        expect($scope.count).toBe(5);

    });

    it('should change counter value', function() {
        $scope.incrementCount();
        expect($scope.count).toBe(6);
    });

});
```

**What I am doing wrong?**

Comment: Your second call to `it` has an extra "i" (`iit`), but that results in this error: "ReferenceError: iit is not defined." Once I removed the extra "i", the test ran fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the angular-mocks dependency, and also you have a typo 'itt' should be 'it' in the should init counter value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
I had an error in declaring of controller: var app = angular.module('app', []);
I was re-declaring it in another place in not proper way.

Comment: `iit` is generally not a typo, it's a (karma) feature to focus on 1 test ;)